# Load XML in C# InnerText

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-services

I have a C# service where I loop every 1 seconds trough a directory looking for XML files.

These XML files may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
<type>freelance</type>
<text>blah</text>
</job>
```

In a foreach I do the following:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlFile);

XmlNode xmltype = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/job/type");
```

And than I would like to use these strings to use in my program, however. Using `xmltype.InnerText` does not work. Documentation on MSDN does not provide me with anything new and I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: What is it "not working"? What result did you get? What did you expect? Can you supply a short working re-create?

Comment: @Richard I tried logging it with `File.AppendAllText("C:\\test\\test.txt", xmltype.InnerText);` but the text file is empty.

Comment: @geedubb I do not get any exception as I am not aware how to debug a Windows service application.

Comment: Please include this information in the question not in comments.

Comment: You can extract the text in the xpath expression and put it into a string: XmlNode xmltype = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/job/type/text()");
string str = xmltype.Value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to check the xml file.whether is there any data or not.
after that take the one particular node check for `innerText`.
for example

This is the Text

```
XmlNode xmlType = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/job/type");

xmlType.innerText = "This is the Text";

xmlType.Value = "Stack";
```

Answer (score 0):

This following console program will output "freelance". I think the issue may be with some of your XML - do *all* of your XML docs follow the same schema? I am guessing that the code fails with a `NullReferenceException` at some point. I've added a null check to protect against this possible scenario.

To help debug your service I tend to use the technique [described here](http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/) to run the app as console application (for easy debugging) or windows service.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{

    static string xmlFile = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
        <job>
        <type>freelance</type>
        <text>blah</text>
        </job>";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlFile);

        XmlNode xmltype = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/job/type");
        if(xmltype==null)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("/job/type not found");
        } else {
           Console.WriteLine(xmltype.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string str = xmltype.Value;
```